# Spark ML Error: Incorrect no. of classes detected while using Linear SVC

Tags: machine-learning, pyspark, classification, svm, apache-spark-ml

I am working on a binary classification problem and using SparkML, I trained and evaluated my data using Random Forest and Logistic Regression models and now I wanted to check how well SVM classifies my data.

***Snippet of my training data***:-

```
+----------+------+
|  spam    | count|
+----------+------+
|        No|197378|
|       Yes|  7652|
+----------+------+

Note:- My dependent variable: 'spam': string (nullable = true)

+-----+------+
|label| count|
+-----+------+
|  0.0|197488|
|  1.0|  7650|
+-----+------+

Note:- label: double (nullable = false)
```

*Updates to my question*:-

```
trainingData.select('label').distinct().show()
+-----+
|label|
+-----+
|  0.0|
|  1.0|
+-----+
```

So, I used below code to fit my training data using ***Linear SVC***:-

```
 pyspark.ml.classification import LinearSVC
 lsvc = LinearSVC()
 # Fit the model
 lsvcModel = lsvc.fit(trainingData)
```

In my data frame, label and dependent variable have only 2 classes, but I get an error saying more classes are detected. Not really sure what's causing this exception.
Any help is much appreciated!

***Error***:-

```
IllegalArgumentException: u'requirement failed: LinearSVC only supports 
binary classification. 3 classes detected in 
LinearSVC_4240bb949b9fad486ec0__labelCol'
```

Comment: Can you please run `trainingData.select('label').distinct().show()` and post the result?

Comment: OK, what is your Spark version?

Comment: `sc.version`  2.3.0.2.6.5.0-292

Answer (score 0):

you can try to convert your label value into a categorical data using `OnehotEncoder` with `handleInvalid` parameter to be "keep"

Comment: `labelIndexer = StringIndexer(inputCol="spam", outputCol="label").setHandleInvalid("keep")`. I don't think it has anything to with conversion here, because the conversion is already done before splitting the data into training and test!

Answer (score 0):

I have same problem.

```
scala> TEST_DF_37849c70_7cd3_4fd6_a9a0_df4de727df25.select("si_37849c70_7cd3_4fd6_a9a0_df4de727df25_logicProp1_lable_left").distinct.show
+-------------------------------------------------------------+
|si_37849c70_7cd3_4fd6_a9a0_df4de727df25_logicProp1_lable_left|
+-------------------------------------------------------------+
|                                                          0.0|
|                                                          1.0|
+-------------------------------------------------------------+
```

**error**: requirement failed: LinearSVC only supports binary classification. 3 classes detected in linearsvc_d18a38204551__labelCol

but in my case, Using StringIndexer with setHandleInvalid("**skip**") option, It works. 
Maybe LeanerSVM have some bug in case of StringIndexer "keep" option.